# ATL COM DLL registration on Window 7 failed to update CLSID section but TypeLib works

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, registry, atl

We are working on a **ATL COM DLL** migration project migrating code from **VC++6 to VC++10** and the **object_map failed to load up**.

It is basically same as problem encountered by 
[swapnil_shinde here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/2d05e1e7-06b7-4440-b73c-58ca98b81664?prof=required)

The **DLL** shown as registered successfully, and shown in **typelib**, but not in the **CLSID**.
**Existing code works fine with VC6 on Window XP but not with VC10 on Window 7.**

The registration is fair standard using **DLLRegisterServer** of the **atlbase.h in VC10**.

Any idea any one?

We think the stackoverflow community is more active and variety of knowledge.
Any additional information we missed out, please ask and we will provide as well.

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**
I'm running as an Administrator, 32 bit app testing on 32 bit window 7.
I have searched the entire registry for the CLSID can still cannot find it.

Comment: Actually there is some redirection mechanism for CLSID in Win7.
Google it, you will get plenty of resource.

Comment: 32/64 bit component? 32/64 bit Windows? Does a regsvr32 succeed?

Comment: Check following..
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457406/regsvr32-failed-to-create-an-entry-under-clsid)

Comment: Thanks all. We have tried this on 32bit window 7, the app is also 32bit. I'm looking at the redirection mechanism at the moment.

Comment: What happens if you try running: regsvr32 YourComponent.dll

Comment: @snowdude it shows as successful. Typelib regiested okay but the CLSID is not registered.

Answer (score 3):

Try registering your object using the `OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO` macro instead. In the header of each object put an reference to the entry after the class declaration, e.g.:

```
class CMyObject { ... class decl ... };
OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(MyObject), CMyObject)
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to run it through the debugger (using regsvr32 as the EXE) and watch what happens in DllRegisterServer.

Comment: We have tried this MARCO as well. The entry map for CLSID is empty. When we build with VC6, the code works. Could it be a bug in VC10's ATL library?

Comment: I'd be surprised. There are a lot of people relying on VC10's ATL code. Does AtlComModuleRegisterServer at least get into the 'for' loop, ie is the object in the map?

Comment: If it's in the map but the CLSID is empty try using IID_MyObject instead of __uuidof(MyObject).