# regsvr32 failed to create an entry under clsid

Tags: visual-c++

I have a VC++ dll, which I want to register on my 32-bit Windows 7 machine using `regsvr32.exe`, however I have some problems with this.

When I register my DLL with `regsvr32.exe`, it shows registration successful, but when I check the entries in `regedit`, there is no entry in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`.

There is only one entry in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\TypeLib` with the `guid` mentioned in the project.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in an administrator command prompt? If not then the registration may be successful, but it's actually being virtualised to your user area. Have a look in the locations mentioned in the [virtualization article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you may see the CLSID there.  If you run from an administrator command prompt then it should appear in the right place.